# Errors in Error Log in Cpanel

Tags: php, server

I found the following error in the error log in the cpanel for my website. I have changed the name to meet the advertiser's TOS. Here is the error:

```
[Tue Nov 04 01:03:23 2014] [error] [client *ip address*] File does not exist: /home/food/public_html/index.php, referer: mywebsite.com/folder/content.html
```

I have built the site using HTML, and have not used PHP at all.

From my PC, I am able to access content.html.

When I contacted the tech support of my hosting service, they could not explain why there are errors in the error log and merely said it is a coding issue.

Please inform how to resolve the error and if I should be concerned, as I am not using a file called index.php (or any other PHP file in the site).  Thanks for your help.

Comment: use `301 redirect` using htaccess file

Comment: I'm a little confused, is mywebsite.com a remote domain?

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting this log correctly, this doesn't look like your hosting company is giving you the correct information.

By referer, I assume apache is indicating the URI which generated the request from your client's domain. Meaning that your client is trying to access /home/food/public_html/index.php on your domain. If it doesn't exist you need to have them correct their referring link/script.